# Why is the Python Code running so long and is there any way to get the output quickly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, factorization

I have a Python Code to get the largest prime factor of a Number and the below is my code
When I give the input to the number up to an 8-digit number takes a few minutes but when I tried running the code for a 12-digit number 600851475143 it took more time and still it didn't give any output or any error.
So is there any way how to get the output for the 12-digit numbers quickly?

```py
def large_prime_fact(num):
    prime_factors=[]
    if num==2 or num==3:
        return(prime_factors.append(num))
    if num%2==0:
        prime_factors.append(2)
    for i in range(3,num,2):
        cnt=0
        if num%i==0:
            for j in range(2,i):
                if i%j==0:
                    cnt+=1
            if cnt==0 and i!=2:
                prime_factors.append(i)
    return prime_factors
if __name__=='__main__':
    number=int(input('Enter the number:'))
    print('The Largest prime factor for',number,'is :',max(large_prime_fact(number)))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "when I tried running the code for a 12 digir number 600851475143 it took more time and still it didn't gave any output " In your own words, how many times do you expect each loop to run for this input? Why? Maybe you can think of some ways to reduce the amount of work that needs to be done? This is really a math question, not a programming question; and I specifically recognize that you are trying to solve a Project Euler problem - you should try to search the Internet for help.

Comment: `return primefactors.append(num)` returns `None`, not the singleton list you just created. Worry about whether your code is *correct* before you worry about how long it takes to run.

Answer (score 0):

As Karl Knechtel pointed out your approach is seriously flawed. Here on SO there are lots of questions about prime numbers and factorization, which you may want to read.

That said, here's my solution. It may still benefit from further optimizations, but it solves your 600851475143 example in about 1ms.

```
##define a prime numbers generator
def prime_gen():
    primes = []
    n = 2
    while n < 2**64:
        if primes == []:
            primes.append(n)
            yield n
        elif len(primes) == 1:
            n = 3
            primes.append(n)
            yield n
        else:
            n += 2
            limit = int(sqrt(n))+1
            for p in takewhile(lambda x:x<limit, primes):
                if n%p==0:
                    break
            else:
                primes.append(n)
                yield n

##factorize and return largest factor
def largest_prime(n):
    target = n
    for x in prime_gen():
        while target % x == 0:
            target //= x
            if target == 1:
                return x
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two algorithms here:

1. An algorithm for finding all factors of `num`, which contains
2. An algorithm for checking the primality of each factor you find

Both algorithms are implemented incredibly inefficiently. The primality tester knows, from the moment it finds a single smaller value which divides it, that it's not prime, but you continue counting *all* the factors of that number, and use the count *solely* to check if it's zero or non-zero. Since the *vast* majority of composite numbers will have a smallish factor, you could just `break` your checking loop as soon as you find even one, knowing it's composite immediately and avoiding huge amounts of work.

Even better, you could pre-compute the prime numbers up to the square root of the target number (note: Only need to go up to the square root because any factor larger than the square root definitionally has a factor below the square root which you could use to find it without exhaustive search). Efficiently computing all prime numbers in a fixed range (especially such a tiny range as the square root of your target number, which is under 1M) can be done *much* more efficiently than repeated trial division (search information on the Sieve of Eratosthenes for a decent algorithm for smallish primes).

Replacing slow per factor primality tests from #2 with a cheap precompute of *all* possible prime factors below the square root (allowing you to cheaply determine any prime factors above the square root) should solve the problem. There are additional optimizations available, but that should get 99% of it.